# Unable to access model values for the angular ui modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I am very new to the angular world (second day) and trying to work around angular ui. I am trying to build my first modal dialog.
The modal dialog is being shown properly but I m not able to use model in that modal dialog.
Here is my [demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSBtEG3yRPxZKmkxsyZ7?p=preview)

Here is what I've done so far:

**In controller:**

```
appRoot.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {
$scope.openDemoModal= function (size) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'ngPartials/_DemoModal.html',
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
            size: size,
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            modalFade: true
        });
    };
});
```

**In index.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <a ng-click="openDemoModal()">Open Modal</a>
</div>
```

**In _DemoModal.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Test Modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
            <input ng-model="testModel"/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**In controller modalCtrl**

```
appRoot.controller('modalCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.test= function () {
        var temp = $scope.testModel;//This shows undefined
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

In modalCtrl **$scope.testModel** always remains undefined no mater what is in the text box.
And if I first set the value of $scope.testModel="some value", it will never change no matter what is in the text box.
What exactly wrong I am doing.

Also I want to know, if is it possible to have communication between **DemoCtrl** and **modalCtrl** ?
For this communication I tried to use concept of **events** as follows:

**In modalCtrl:**

```
 $scope.test= function () {
      //var temp = $scope.testModel;//This shows undefined
      $scope.$emit('someEvent', 'some args');
 };
```

**In DemoCtrl:**

```
$scope.$on('someEvent', function (event, args) {
        alert('event called');
});
```

But this is also not working.
What exactly I am doing wrong. Is I am creating angular modal in a wrong way?
Any help will be great for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you gather your code in a jsfiddle/plunk example

Comment: here is the plunker I created: http://plnkr.co/edit/qSBtEG3yRPxZKmkxsyZ7?p=preview

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a prototypical inheritance issue that occurs with teh angular ui bootstrap modal. I can't say I know the exact cause of this (Other than it being $scope related) but I've encountered this many times before and my workaround is to define the main model object on the scope of the modal controller as soon it is created, basically try this;

```
appRoot.controller('modalCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    //Declare the model explicitly on the controller rather than implicitly on the view
    $scope.testModel="";
    $scope.test= function () {
        var temp = $scope.testModel;//This shows undefined
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

**EDIT:**

Examining the `$scope` of the modal shows that the `testModel` object exists on the `$$childTail` scope, meaning the modal has created a new child `$scope` for itself, and is binding `testModel` to that `$scope`. A workaround is to use `ng-model="$parent.testModel"` to reference the parent `$scope` (the correct scope, the one we defined for the modal).

[Working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jWqa6Dijz0DQhDwBbtPR?p=preview).

Comment: please check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qSBtEG3yRPxZKmkxsyZ7?p=preview

Comment: As per your solution the value will always remains empty string ""

Comment: Can you also help me regarding the inter controller communication... I have created this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OmdSOuuFxeyF7I94ohCF?p=preview

Comment: @SaurabhLprocks I think ebram tharwat answered your question? Although I usually use a service rather than `$emit`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having a scope issue. In other words, your model `testModel` is created inside a different scope, a `child scope`. So to fix your issue simply use object attached to your modal scope rather than a variable:

```
appRoot.controller('modalCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.data = {
    testModel: ""
  };
  $scope.test = function() {
    var temp = $scope.data.testModel; //This shows undefined
    alert(temp);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Check an updated ***[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCdeJj5bjWR2sNAbQpbZ?p=preview)***

***UPDATE:***

Now you want a way to communicate between two controllers using [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit). To fix your code you need just to specify the `parent scope` while creating the `modal`, so you just need to update your code like this:

```
$scope.openDemoModal = function(size) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: '_DemoModal.html',
      controller: 'modalCtrl',
      size: size,
      backdrop: true,
      keyboard: true,
      modalFade: true,
      scope: $scope // that's what you need to add.
    });
  };
```

***[Working demo for update](http://plnkr.co/edit/QE35FUgGJAiTWM3JAE5V?p=preview)***

Comment: Yah! its working now.. can you please also way to communicate between two controllers. see this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OmdSOuuFxeyF7I94ohCF?p=preview