# Bind data from table to modal

Tags: angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, http-get

I'm trying to get the data from a row (once clicked) to fill a pop-up modal window with that row of data. And then you should be able to change the data and resubmit, updating the data in the table.

The below is the code for firstly my table, and then the modal.

The data that fills the table is retrieved through a $http get request, but when the data inside the modal is changed and the table is updated subsequently, the json file retrieved does not need to be updated.

I feel I've done a large amount of searching, but all the other answers have pointed me in different directions to what I seek, or I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I'm not seeking a full solution, but if anyone could guide me in the right direction that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance for any knowledge you can share on this.

To reiterate, this is what I'm struggling with:

> "I'm trying to get the data from a row (once clicked) to fill a pop-up modal window with that row of data. And then you should be able to change the data and resubmit, updating the data in the table. "

```
<body>
  <div data-ng-app="peopleInformation" data-ng-controller="myCtrl" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Essential Information</div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Nickname</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr data-ng-repeat="data in myData" data-ng-click="modify(data)">
                        <td>{{ data.FirstName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.LastName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.Age }}</td>
                        <td>{{ data.Nickname }}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>                    
              </table>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-ng-click="new()">Add
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here is my modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">   
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Your row of data</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" name="modelData">
              <form class="form-horizontal pull-left form-width" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="first">First Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first" ng-bind="FirstName">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="last">Last Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last" ng-bind="LastName">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="age">Age:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" ng-bind="Age">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="nick">Nickname:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nick" ng-bind="Nickname">
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my JS so far too:

```
var app = angular.module('peopleInformation', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {

$http.get("xxxxxx.json").success(function(response){
    $scope.myData = response.People;
});

$scope.modify = function(currentData){

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            details: function() {
                return currentData;
            }
        }   
    });

};
});   

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, details){
$scope.FirstName = details.FirstName;
$scope.LastName = details.LastName;
$scope.Age = details.Age;
$scope.Nickname = details.Nickname;
});
```

Comment: what problem you are facing??

Comment: I'm trying to get the data from a row (once clicked) to fill a pop-up modal window with that row of data. And then you should be able to change the data and resubmit, updating the data in the table.

Comment: so you are not getting data am i right???

Comment: Essentially yes, however I don't know how to approach even getting the data, so..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access model values for the angular ui modal dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139245/unable-to-access-model-values-for-the-angular-ui-modal-dialog)